# VUE (Quasar) How can I access my localstorage data without the need for refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, quasar-framework

I have a standard Quasar CLI project with layouts/MainLayout.vue and pages/Index.vue.  Those are the only two files I have altered after the Quasar CLI create process.

In MainLayout.vue I store some data in localStorage, ex.
this.$q.localStorage.set('curriculumId', 0)

In Index.vue when I try to get this data, ex.
var s = this.$q.localStorage.getItem('curriculumId')

I get null as a response

If I try to get this data in mounted() (and I have tried in all other lifecycle hooks), I again get null, ex.

```
if (this.$q.localStorage.has('curriculumId')) {
      console.log('mounted - success')
    } else {
      console.log('mounted - failed')
}
```

CONSOLE
mounted - failed

However, when I hit refresh, all of my data is available.

My routes.js is system created

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') }
    ]
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '*', component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the Localstorage variable through vuex store.
i.e in  store/store-curriculum.js

```
import { LocalStorage, SessionStorage } from 'quasar'
const state = {
   curriculumId: Localstorage.getItem('curriculumId') | null
}
const getters = {
   curriculumId: (state) => state.curriculumId,
}
const mutation = {}
const action = {}
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

Then add the following in your Index.vue file

```
if (this.$store.getters.curriculum.curriculumId)) {
   console.log('mounted - success')
} else {
   console.log('mounted - failed')
}
```